# Zend framework layout path incorrect

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i have a problem with zend layouts...if I am on the index:

`www.mysite.com/`

That's ok because layouts load correctly the files like this `assets/images/etc`

But if i go to: `www.mysite.com/modules/controller/index` or `www.mysite.com/controller/index`, the layouts will try to load file in `modules/controller/assets` or in `controller/assets`

I don't know if the problem can be in the **.htaccess** file or **Bootstrap.php** or **application.ini**

How can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a ZF/PHP problem. Just ensure you use absolute paths in your layout file (i.e. paths that start with a `/`), then you won't have this issue.

Comment: With this solution, I have to use absolute paths even if I want to insert an image in www.mysite.com/modules/controller/index, I don't like it...